# ModSecurity: How to disable error logging for single rule?

Tags: mod-security

Here is my configurations:

```
SecDefaultAction "phase:1,log,deny,status:403"
SecDefaultAction "phase:2,log,deny,status:403"

SecRule REQUEST_URI "@pm logging_test" \
    "id:100,\
    phase:1,\
    pass,nolog,\
    capture,\
    msg:'Test Error Logging'"
```

but I still get the entries in the error.log

In Manual, nolog means

> Prevents rule matches from appearing in both the error and audit logs.

How to disable error.log for a specific rule?

Comment: The `pass,nolog` has some negation effect, [according to this discussion](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/issues/2614). Also, if it's appearing in error log, you may have re-look into the request you're sending. Please be specific while posting question - modsecurity version, webserver version, other rulesets etc.

Comment: "but I still get the entries in the error.log" - entries for what? For the mentioned rule? Could you show those entries?

Comment: I tried reproduce your issue both on mod_security2 + Apache and libmodsecurity3 + Nginx, but I was not able to reproduce it. I just copied your rule (and your `SecDefaultAction` lines, and sent this curl request: `curl http://localhost/logging_test`. I didn't get any log entries. Then I removed the `nolog` action and repeat the request against both server, then I got the lines for triggered rules.